# Prints the speech marks in a list

Tags: python

When I have a print("") and say i put:

```
things = ["Number 1", "Number 2"]
print(things[0])
```

It will print:

```
['Number 1']
```

when I do:

```
print(things)
```

it will print:

```
['Number 1', 'Number 2]
```

I dont know whats wrong?

Im on a Mac OS X Mountain Lion 10.9

Python 2.something

Comment: Please provide error accurately, `things[1]` is not even `Number 1`

Comment: It works fine: http://repl.it/S9x

Comment: to get this output, you have to say `print(things[:1])` and that's the representation of a list.

Comment: but if i just print(things) it will come up with the speechmarks

Comment: If you are trying to print a list you need to tell python what you want it to look like.  For example... brackets on both sides? Quotations for elements or no quotations? Elements delimited by coma or tab or pipe character?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write the following line, you are telling `Python` to create a list containing two objects of type `String`. The `"` are not preserved in the process of telling Python about the strings.

```
things = ["Number 1", "Number 2"]
```

When you write `print(things[1])`, Python will print it however it likes.

If you want to print it a particular way, you need to specify the formatting explicitly.

For example, if you want to have the quotation marks in the print, you could do the following, which will put literal double quotes around the value of `things[0]` before printing it.

```
print('"%s"'  % things[0])
```

Output:

```
"Number 1"
```

As another example, if you just want a plain print with no quotations, you could do the following.

```
print('%s'  % things[0])
```

Output:

```
Number 1
```

Comment: im not sure what you mean by "you need to write the printing explicitly"

Comment: @user3595018, I agree that the original phrasing was a little confusing. :)

Comment: @user3595018 Yes it does. What do you want it to print?

Comment: when i put: print("%s" % things) it will print ['Number 1', 'Number 2]

Comment: When you write that you are asking python to convert a list to a string for you automatically.

Comment: no I want it to just display a space between the inputs

Comment: like: Number 1 Number 2

Comment: @user3595018 print(' '.join (things))